# is there a preg_replace for mysql or way to accomplish the same.?

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, mariadb

I'm trying to replace content in a column - for example.

```
UPDATE table 
SET column1 = REGEXP_REPLACE(
    column1, 
    '<span style="red">(*.)</span>', 
    '<div class="something">$1</div>'
)
```

My database version:
    $ mysql -V
    mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.22-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

Comment: Do this in your PHP code using [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Comment: have mysql 8.0.x? then yes you can, else no.

Comment: can you show an example.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mariadb has [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/regexp_replace/)
 so you do this:

```
SET @a := '<span style="red">test</span>';

SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
    @a,
    '<span style="red">(.*)</span>',
    '<div class="something">\\1</div>'
) AS reorder_name;
```

```
| reorder_name                      |
| :-------------------------------- |
| <div class="something">test</div> |
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=9ba8748315060d06922eaa5fbb00996d)*